# Parametric Problem: Throwing a Dart <Test Review>

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

Yup it's me ... Parametrics, who would have thought xD! Anyways, again ... I am doing review and I really need this grade to get an A in math class; that's why I am asking questions here. And you guys are wonderful enough to answer the test review questions. Have a test tomorrow, so I am getting prepared. Anyways, back to topic: this is the third-to-last question on test-review, and it says:

> A dart is thrown from a point 5 feet above the ground with an inital velocity of 58 ft/sec and angle of elvation of $41 ^\circ$. Assume the onnly force acting on the dart is gravity. What is the maximum height reached by the dart? When and will the dart hit the ground? **SHOW ALL WORK**.

[You know from my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801346/parametric-problem-kicking-a-football-getting-ready-for-test) that I don't understand what the question is even trying to say. So far, I did 20 questions out of 24 alone, and I need help on this. Please help me again, Math StackExchange Site!

Remember we are on Parametric Unit.

EDIT :

### Equations(In my notes.. not sure if there are more.)

[image]

### Examples

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must find the equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. The problems gives you the values of $x(0),x^\prime(0),y(0),y^\prime(0)$ and $y^{\prime\prime}(0)$ which is enough to find the constants of integration and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. You will need a bit of trig to find $x^\prime(0)$ and $y^\prime(0)$.

Comment: Huh @JohnWaylandBales i have the notes if thats what your asking for... i dont understand the other parts you said.. can you anwser it, so i can apply the logic on my test tommorow please?

Comment: The problem as stated it gives you enough information to figure out the values I mentioned in my other comment. Do you know how to find those values? This is pretty standard stuff so I know that your teacher discussed it.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales this is the problem... my teacher discussed about it. But this unit, i havent been on my streak. So i kinda slacked of :( , im paying the price now.. Anways how would you do it John?

Comment: $x(0)$ and $y(0)$ are the initial values of $x$ and $y$ when $t=0$ and those values are clearly stated. What are they. For $x^\prime(0)$ and $y^\prime(0)$ you will need to find the horizontal and vertical components of the initial velocity, and the velocity (speed plus direction) is given. And the acceleration $y^{\prime\prime}(t)$ will be the constant acceleration due to gravity acting downward (so it's negative). You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: Ok. One second. Ill respond soon @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales lets take this one step at a time... So first what i am finding is the max height, the time it will take to hit ground, and what is the x distance i assume when it says where.. Am i right John?

Comment: Correct. Once you find the equation for $y(t)$ you will find that it is the equation of a parabola which is concave downward. $y(t)$ will achieve a maximum value when $y^\prime(t)=0$ and the dart will hit the ground when $y(t)=0$ for some positive $t$. But first you must find $y(t)$. Can you tell me from the given information what $y(0)$ the initial value of the height $y$ is? You can assume that $x(0)=0$ since that is the initial horizontal position of the dart, but the problem tells you what the initial height of the dart is.

Comment: I have been assuming that this is for a calculus class. Is that correct?

Comment: No lol. Its precalcus.. everyone thinks its calculus

Comment: OK, now it's clear why you do not understand. For precalculus you will have to use an equation. I don't remember the formula but give me a few minutes and I will derive it.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales i posted the equations now... sorry my handwriting on that one is kinda bad :(

Comment: Actually they are the same, you use $X_T$ where I used $x(t)$, etc and wrote the $t^2$ term first instead of last. Either way, it doesn't matter, just a choice of style.

Answer (score 1):

For a pre-calculus class you will probably have a set of parametric equations of the following form although your teacher might use different variables.

Given the initial position $(x(0),y(0))$, initial speed $\vert v \vert$ and initial direction of motion $\theta$ and acceleration $g$ due to gravity, then

\begin{equation}
x(t)=x(0)+\vert v\vert t\cos\theta
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y(t)=y(0)+\vert v\vert t\sin\theta-\frac{g}{2}t^2
\end{equation}

For this exercise $x(0)=0,\,y(0)=5$ ft, $\vert v\vert=58$ ft/sec, $\theta=41^\circ$ and $g=32\text{ft/sec}^2$.

Substitute the values into the formula for $y(t)$ and you will get a second degree polynomial equation for $t$ (of the form $y=at^2+bt+c)$. Its graph will be a parabola which is concave downward and $y$ will achieve its greatest value at the vertex which occurs when $t=-\frac{b}{2a}$. Find that value of $t$ and substitute into the equation for $y$ to find out how high the dart goes.

The dart will hit the ground when $y(t)=0$ and $t>0$. So set the equation for $y(t)=0$ and solve for $t$ to find out when the dart will  hit the ground. You only need to use $x(t)$ if you are asked how far the dart goes.

Comment: Wait did you see the equations i posted above?

Comment: And the examples? Because my examples and the way you are doing is diffrent?

Comment: its not the same way as my teacher did though :/

Comment: But you did x(t)=x(0)+|v|tcosθ ... i did it like x(t) = cos(theta)*t

Comment: Because usually $x(0)=0$ but it does not always have to be. And $\vert v\vert\cos\theta$ is the horizontal component of the velocity vector $v$ so you can write it either as $(\vert v\vert\cos\theta)t$ or as $(\vert v\vert t \cos\theta)$ or $\vert v\vert\cos(\theta)\cdot t$ it really does not matter.

Comment: Anyway, I have to go now. But I got the following values: Reaches a height of $26.7$ feet after $1.189$ sec, hits the ground after $2.5$ seconds and goes $109.4$ ft.

Comment: Ok i solved everything...i actually didnt see your thing

Comment: BUT...... idk how to solve maximum height. I always get negative number!!

Comment: How in the world od i get Max height?? I need to know before i sleep..

Comment: Im about to ask a new question.... i need to get anwser